# Using Firebase Auth to store additional information

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

Does anyone know if it is possible and how to use firebase auth to give additional information, like the name of the User?

I created this method but it only stores emails and passwords.

```
    public void create()
    {
        FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(emailInput.text, passwordInput.text).ContinueWith((task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Firebase.FirebaseException e = task.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions[0] as Firebase.FirebaseException;
                GetErrorMessage((AuthError)e.ErrorCode);
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Firebase.FirebaseException e = task.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions[0] as Firebase.FirebaseException;
                GetErrorMessage((AuthError)e.ErrorCode);
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                print("Created user");
                return;

            }
        }));


    }
```

I'm new in unity and I started using firebase for about one week. 
Sorry, if I asked something obvious, but I searched for days and the documentation is scarce.

Thanks

Comment: This is [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 2):

Use the `FirebaseUser.UpdateUserProfileAsync`

```
public void SetPlayerNameAndImage(string playerName, string imageUrl)
{
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser;
    if (user != null)
    {
        Firebase.Auth.UserProfile profile = new Firebase.Auth.UserProfile
        {
            DisplayName = playerName,
            PhotoUrl = new System.Uri(imageUrl),
        };
        user.UpdateUserProfileAsync(profile).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("UpdateUserProfileAsync was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("UpdateUserProfileAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }

            Debug.Log("User profile updated successfully.");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication only has the ability to store per user in the dedicated fields for the [user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/manage-users#update_a_users_profile) and [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).  The blob of data for custom claims is limited to 1000 bytes of JSON, and it can only be written with a backend SDK, not the Unity client SDK.  While you certainly can store data about the user in custom claims, that's not what it's intended to be used for (it's meant for granted access using backend security mechanisms).

What you should do instead is use a database, such as [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start) or [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) to store per-user information, keyed by the Firbase Auth UID, and protect that with security rules so that each user can only access the data that you would like them to access.